# append multiple html meta tags to head with a for loop

Tags: php, html, twig, shopware, shopware6

i'm currently working on a shopware plugin, where I add some meta data to the html tag **head**. I use twig to extend a template and add some some code to it.
I trigger an event which passes the array of meta entities **mykn_metaFields** to my twig-template. In my twig-template I loop over **mykn_metaFields** and apply the values of these entities to meta-tag attributes.

Twig code:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_head_meta_tags %}
    {{parent()}}
    {{dump()}}
    {% if page.mykn_metaFields.total > 0 %}
        {% for metaField in page.mykn_metaFields.entities.elements %}
            {% if metaField.active == true %}
                <meta name="{{metaField.name}}" content="{{metaField.value}}">
                {{dump(metaField)}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

expected html Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <meta name="foo" content="foo">
        <meta name="bar" content="bar">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...

    </body>
</html>
```

returned html Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta name="foo" content="foo">
        <meta name="bar" content="bar">
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Question: Why doesn't it append the meta tags to the head?

This is how i pass the variable mykn_metaFields:

````
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPluginRoot\Subscriber\Storefront\Page;

use Shopware\Storefront\Page\GenericPageLoadedEvent;
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;

class PageLoadedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $metaFieldRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $metaFieldRepository)
    {
        $this->metaFieldRepository = $metaFieldRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            GenericPageLoadedEvent::class => 'addMetaToHead'
        ];
    }

    public function addMetaToHead(GenericPageLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true));

        $metaFields = $this->metaFieldRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext()); 
        $array = ['mykn_metaFields' => $metaFields];
        $event->getPage()->assign($array);
    }
}```
````

**EDIT**
I solved this problem by removing `dump()` in my twig-template. I guess shopware renders it as something like a `pre`-tag which puts it in the body.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? There are multiple conditions in your code that could block that output

Comment: @NicoHaase I use `dump()` to debug. `dump()` returns as expected each entity in `mykn_metaFields`. Since `mykn_metaFields` has 2 elements  and each elelment has the value `true` when accessing the property `active` we enter the for loop if statement. Idk which condition would block it

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you did replace the line `{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}` in `base.html.twig` with your custom template right?

Comment: @DarkBee if I understood your question right, then yes. My twig-template extends `@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig`, which then replaces the line `{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}` in `base.html.twig`

Comment: What does `dump(page.mykn_metaFields.total)` yield? Did you try to add dumps in each of the nested segments?

Comment: @NicoHaase `dump(page.mykn_metaFields.total)` yields the number (:=2) of elements in array `mykn_metaFields` . If I try to `dump(metaField)` for all elements in `mykn_metaFields` I get every Entity with it's properties.

Comment: What about `{% if metaField.active %}`? Does this help?

Comment: @NicoHaase unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `page.mykn_metaFields` is a `EntitySearchResult` in that case you should be able to loop directly over that `SearchResult`, no need to access the internal `elements` property and also no need to check the total beforehand.

this would already simplify your twig template:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_head_meta_tags %}
    {{parent()}}
    {{dump()}}
    {% for metaField in page.mykn_metaFields %}
        {% if metaField.active == true %}
            <meta name="{{metaField.name}}" content="{{metaField.value}}">
            {{dump(metaField)}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Additionally i would filter the inactive metaFields already on the backend side, where you load your own entity and add it to the page object.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('active', true);
$result = $metaFieldRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

That way you can get rid of the `active` check in the template, and the template is greatly simplified:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/meta.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_head_meta_tags %}
    {{parent()}}
    {{dump()}}
    {% for metaField in page.mykn_metaFields %}
        <meta name="{{metaField.name}}" content="{{metaField.value}}">
        {{dump(metaField)}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thx for the tip! I simplified it now, but my problem remain the same. There is no meta added to the head-tag :c